# Is Label Name in Gremlin Case Sensitive?

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

Is Label Name in Gremlin Cosmos DB, Case Sensitive? For example is `g.V().hasLabel('User')` different with `g.V().hasLabel('user')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. it is. You can test it by adding some instances to the database. For example:

```
g.addV('User');
g.addV('User');
g.addV('User');
```

Then get query by `g.V().hasLabel('user')`, the result will be null.